# Table missing from database when using CreateDatabase()

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities(theParameter);
```

Here is theParameter:

```
 metadata=res://*/Models.My.csdl|res://*/Models.My.ssdl|res://*/Models.My.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=[correctIpAddress];Initial Catalog=testDbName;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'
```

When I add watch to db, it has many tables, among them the table tblTestTable. After that I do:

```
db.CreateDatabase();
```

And in the newly created database there is no tblTestTable table. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you doing `AcceptChanges()`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I don't understand. How do you mean 'do AcceptChanges()' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table wasn't creating because it didn't have a primary key.
Once I set it, it was created along with the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

> When I add watch to db, it has many tables, among them the table
>   tblTestTable.

I guess you mean that you add a watch in the debugger on an `ObjectContext` instance called `db` and you are watching the `ObjectSet<T>`s that are properties in your derived context and one of those properties is called `tblTestTable`, right?

Generally there is no strict one-to-one relation between an `ObjectSet<T>` and a table in the database. You can have an ObjectSet in your context that doesn't represent its own table, for example:

- If the entity `T` of an `ObjectSet<T>`/`tblTestTable` is derived from another base entity and this inheritance is mapped with table-per-hierarchy strategy both entities will be using the same table, usually named like the base entity. (Normally such a separate set for a derived entity is not required, but it is possible.) In this case `tblTestTable` would not have its own table in the database.
- A single table can be split into more than one entity (which is called "Table-Splitting"). You could have two or more ObjectSets in your context but all of them will use the same table.

Even the other way around is possible: You can have two ObjectSets in your context but they will generate three tables. This would happen if the two entities are related by a many-to-many relationship that gets represented by an additional third join table in the database without its own ObjectSet.

These are only some pointers what *could* be the reason. Without seeing the details of your model and relationships it is difficult to give a more specific answer to your question.